# jquery recursive function newbie

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

I want to run jquery recursive function. but my code doesn't work. need help to fix it

```
function inserting(a, b){
    a = typeof a !== 'undefined' ? a : 0;
    b = typeof b !== 'undefined' ? b : 50;
    if(a < 5000){
        $.get("http://domain.com/process-query.php?start="+a+"&limit="+b,function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr){
            if(statusTxt=="success"){
                $("body").append(responseTxt);
                a = a + b;
                inserting(a,b);
            }
            if(statusTxt=="error")
                alert("Error: "+xhr.status+": "+xhr.statusText);
        });
    }
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    inserting(100, 50);
});
```

Thanks for your help

FYI: process-query.php will print some text based on parameter a and b

Comment: what you got the error..???

Comment: I'm not trying to be smug or offensive and I could just be plain wrong, but using an Ajax function/callback with recursion just seems like a code smell to me.  I can't put my finger on it, but this code just screams YIKES! to me.  But then again, it could be brilliant and I'm just not getting past the initial reaction.

Comment: If that's an asynchronous Ajax call then your code isn't recursive. As for "doesn't work", what is it supposed to do, and what does it currently do? Any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What happens? What should happen? How are they different? What error messages are reported on the JavaScript console? What HTTP requests are visible in your browser's developer tools Net tab? Are they the requests that you expect? if you add `console.log()` statements, are the values of the variables the values they should be?

Comment: couldn't a for loop do what you want to do? it seems to me that `for (x = a; x < 5000; x += b) {}` would do the same...

Comment: @nnnnnn could you explain why it wouldn't be recursive?

Comment: @basilikum - Assuming async Ajax, which I hope it is so it doesn't lock up the browser, the callback from each `$.get()` function won't be invoked until some point after `inserting()` has finished and it is that anonymous callback function that calls `inserting()` again. It's kind of pseudo-almost-recursion, but at no point would `inserting()` actually call itself, and at no time will there be a partly completed `inserting()` waiting on the results of another call to `inserting()`.

Comment: sorry all. my code actually works, my mistake on process-query.php, thanks fol all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working acutally:
http://jsfiddle.net/balintbako/4ZFDU/

A bit simplified version, so you can see the "recursion" or whatever that is with ajax :)

```
function inserting(a){
    if (a < 5){
        $.get("/echo/jsonp", function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr){
            if(statusTxt == "success"){                
                $("div").append("<p>"+ a + "<p>");
                a = a + 1;
                inserting(a);                
            }
            if(statusTxt == "error")
                alert("Error: "+xhr.status+": "+xhr.statusText);
        });
    }
}
inserting(3);
```

Comment: thanks it works. my code actually works too, my mistake on process-query.php. sorry all